# Macro Shortcut not working (Personal Workbook)

Tags: excel, keyboard-shortcuts

I've been using this quick solver macro (created using Record Macro) at work, but recently the shortcut stopped functioning.

I've seen other people fix a similar issue when they realized that the name of their personal macros had changed as displayed in the Excel list of macros, but I'm not seeing that issue here.

It runs fine if I pick it from the developer tab, it's just that the keyboard doesn't work, which is super aggravating.  Does anyone have any ideas what might be causing this?

I'm on Windows10, using Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus (16.0.12527.21296 64-bit)

Here is the code as text:

```
Sub Break_Solver ()

Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+L

Range("U104").GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Range("U7")
Range("T108").GoalSeek Goal:=0, ChangingCell:=Range("T7")
Range("S104").GoalSeek Goal:=9000, ChangingCell:=Range("S7")
Range("R113").GoalSeek Goal:=1.2, ChangingCell:=Range("R7")

End Sub
```

[Picture of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLdK1.png)
[Picture of macro in Developer tab list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ivIC.png)

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68367577/edit) to include your code as text

Comment: In your "Picture of macro in Developer tab list" I assume you've checked in OPTIONS that the shortcut IS still assigned?

Comment: Thanks, Stax - still asigned!

Comment: Clutching at straws now... I had code glitch once a long time ago, and after much debugging the solution was to copy the module text to Notepad, delete the module, save the workbook, create a new Module and paste the text back in. (exporting, deleting and reimporting the Module (.bas file) did Not work). Also, there's a way to assign a shortcut key through VBA (Google "Application.MacroOptions" learnexcelmacro.com). Just possibly, doing it through code (not UI) might be a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

search for PERSONAL.XLSB
Open this file under XLSTART Folder.

Comment: In the question they state they do not think it is a problem with their personal macros list.  If they go to this file and open it, will that solve their problem or is there something else for them to do?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).